# processing array with duplicates

Tags: ruby

I have an array

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D']
```

and I have to go thru all the elements, do something depending on whether the is the last occurance or not, and remove the element after processing it.

The elements are already sorted if that matters.

I'm looking for something efficient. Any suggestions?

Her what I have until now. THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED but not sure it is very efficient.

```
    a = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D']

while !a.empty?
  b = a.shift

  unless a.count(b) > 0
    p "unique #{b}"
  else
    p "duplicate #{b}"
  end
end
```

and it produces

```
"unique A"
"duplicate B"
"unique B"
"unique C"
"duplicate D"
"unique D"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far and where you got stuck. Stack Overflow isn't a good place to ask other people to write code for you.

Comment: Sure, I will update the code. Thank you so much for your support. I do appreciate your kind help.

Comment: If array is **sorted** and you really need **efficient** solution, just iterate it with `each_with_index` and check if `a[i]` equals to `a[i-1]` or `a[i+1]`. Best speed/memory solution.

Answer (score 4):

Simple way:

```
array = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"]

array.group_by{|e| e}.each do |key,value| 
  *duplicate,  uniq = value
  duplicate.map do |e|
    puts "Duplicate #{e}"
  end
  puts "Unique #{uniq}"
end
```

As per **[Stefan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537508/processing-array-with-duplicates/44537922#comment-76073917)** and suggestion, shorter way is:

```
array.chunk_while(&:==).each do |*duplicate, uniq|
  duplicate.map do |e|
    puts "Duplicate #{e}"
  end
  puts "Unique #{uniq}"
end


# Above both will give the same Output:
---------------------------------------
Unique A
Duplicate B
Unique B
Unique C
Duplicate D
Unique D
```

Comment: it's be faster to build `uniq_elements` like this: `array.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |memo, x| memo[x] += 1; memo }.select { |k,v| v > 0 }.keys`

Comment: I must process all items so  I have to loop thru all of them and for each one act differently according to the fact that the element is unique or now (see updated code above).

Comment: @GaganGami "Unique B / Duplicate B" should be the other way round, i.e. "Duplicate B" and then "Unique B". "Unique" means that no similar element is coming afterwards.

Comment: @Stefan : ok got it

Comment: @Stefan : now ?

Comment: Nice one, I like splats :-) Even shorter: `.each do |key, (*duplicate, uniq)|`. And you can even remove that unused `key` argument if you replace `group_by { |e| e }` with `chunk_while(&:==)`

Comment: @Stefan : yes I was not knowing about this way, but I guess it is easy to understand, in block people might get confused, what is happening

Comment: @Stefan: I learn new thing `chunk_while(&:==)` great, updated my answer with same ;)

Comment: [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) returns a hash with key-value pairs `k=>arr`. Do we know if the ordering of the keys is consistent with their ordering in the receiver, of if the ordering of the elements of each value `arr` are similarly consistent. I expect both are, but the doc is mute on that. Also, the last key of a group is to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code and expected output, I think this is an efficient way to do what you're looking for:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D']

a.each_index do |i|
  if i < a.length - 1 && a[i+1] == a[i]
    puts "This is not the last occurrence of #{a[i]}"
  else
    puts "This is the last occurrence of #{a[i]}"
  end
end

# Output:
# This is the last occurrence of A
# This is not the last occurrence of B
# This is the last occurrence of B
# This is the last occurrence of C
# This is not the last occurrence of D
# This is the last occurrence of D
```

But I want to reiterate the importance of the wording in my output versus yours. This is not about whether the value is unique or not in the input. It seems to be about whether the value is the *last* occurrence within the input or not.

Comment: `for i in 0...a.length do` can be expressed as `a.each_index do |i|`

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I've edited the code. I don't write much Ruby, so I definitely appreciate the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to the answer of @GaganGami but using [`chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while).

```
a.chunk_while { |a,b| a == b }
 .each do |*list,last|
   list.each { |e| puts "duplicate #{e}" }
   puts "unique #{last}"
 end
```

`chunk_while`splits the array into sub arrays when the element changes.

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'].chunk_while { |a,b| a == b }.to_a
# => [["A"], ["B", "B"], ["C"], ["D", "D"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP stated that the elements of `a` are sorted, but that is not required by the method I propose. It also maintains array-order, which could be important for the "do something" code performed for each element to be removed. It does so with no performance penalty over the case where the array is already sorted.

For the array

```
['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```

I assume that some code is to be executed for `'A'`, `'C'` the second `'B'` and the second `'D'`, *in that order*, after which a new array

```
['B', 'D']
```

is returned.

**Code**

```
def do_something(e) end

def process_last_dup(a)    
  a.dup.
    tap do |b|
      b.each_with_index.
        reverse_each.
        uniq(&:first).
        reverse_each { |_,i| do_something(a[i]) }.
        each { |_,i| b.delete_at(i) }
    end
end
```

**Example**

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D']

process_last_dup(a)
  #=> ["B", "D"]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
b = a.dup
  #=> ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"]
c = b.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"]:each_with_index>
d = c.reverse_each
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["A",..., "D"]:each_with_index>:reverse_each>
```

Notice that `d` can be thought of as a "compound" enumerator. We can convert it to an array to see the elements it will generate and pass to `uniq`.

```
d.to_a
  #=> [["D", 5], ["D", 4], ["C", 3], ["B", 2], ["B", 1], ["A", 0]]
```

Continuing,

```
e = d.uniq(&:first)
  #=> [["D", 5], ["C", 3], ["B", 2], ["A", 0]]
e.reverse_each { |_,i| do_something(a[i]) }
```

`reverse_each` is used so that `do_something` is first executed for `'A'`, then for the second `'B'`, and so on.

```
e.each { |_,i| b.delete_at(i) }
b #=> ["B", "D"]
```

If `a` is to be modified in place replace `a.dup.` with `a.`.

Readers may have noticed that the code I gave at the beginning used [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) so that `tap`'s block variable `b`, which initially equals `a.dup`, will be returned after it has been modified within `tap`'s block, rather than explicitly setting `b = a.sup` at the beginning and `b` at the end, as I've done in my step-by-step explanation. Both approaches yield the same result, of course.

The doc for [Enumerable#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) does not specify whether the first element is kept, but it does reference [Array.uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq), which does keep the first. If there is any uneasiness about that one could always replace `reverse_each` with `reverse` so that `Array.uniq` would be used.